# Constraining more than one IntVarArray

Tags: or-tools

I'm working with several IntVarArray-s in a model in a way that there are cross-dependencies between their elements. Is this the correct way to use them as parameter for the MakePhase method?

```
var nr = 10;
var fLoc = s.MakeIntVarArray(nr, 0, 1);
var gLoc = s.MakeIntVarArray(nr, 0, 1);
// ... create other arrays

// ... constrain the arrays

// collect them
var decisions = new IntVarVector();

decisions.AddRange(fLoc);
decisions.AddRange(gLoc
//... add other arrays to decisions

// call MakePhase
solver.MakePhase(decisions, ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this works.

Please make sure that either the order is the right one, or choose a variable selection strategy that is dynamic like CHOOSE_MIN_SIZE_LOWEST_MIN.